# Does anyone have information on 3BA to 4BA signature format conversion?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, byte

Does anyone have information on 3BA to 4BA signature format conversion?

We are getting 3 Byte array signature format from pinpad device and now we need to convert it to 4 Byte Array format.

Any information would be helpful.

062,080,0^062,080,0^062,080,0^062,080,0^062,080,0^062,080,0^062,080,0^062,080,0^062,080,0^062,080,0^062,080,0^062,080,0^062,080,0^062,080,0^062,081,0^062,081,0^062,081,0^062,081,0^062,081,0^062,082,0^062,082,0^062,082,0^062,083,0^062,083,0^062,084,0^062,084,0^062,085,0^061,086,0^061,086,0^061,087,0^061,088,0^061,088,0^061,089,0^061,089,0^061,090,0^061,091,0^061,091,0^061,092,0^061,092,0^061,092,0^060,093,0^060,093,0^060,094,0^060,094,0^060,094,0^060,095,0^060,095,0^060,095,1^050,086,0^050,086,0^050,086,0^050,086,0^050,086,0^050,086,0^050,086,0^050,086,0^050,086,0^050,085,0^050,085,0^050,085,0^050,085,0^050,085,0^050,085,0^050,084,0^050,084,0^050,084,0^050,084,0^050,083,0^050,083,0^050,083,0^050,082,0^050,082,0^050,081,0^050,081,0^051,081,0^051,080,0^051,080,0^052,080,0^052,080,0^053,079,0^053,079,0^054,079,0^055,079,0^055,079,0^057,079,0^057,079,0^058,079,0^060,079,0^060,079,0^060,079,0^061,079,0^063,079,0^063,079,0^064,079,0^064,079,0^065,080,0^066,080,0^066,080,0^067,081,0^067,081,0^068,081,0^068,082,0^068,082,0^069,083,0^069,083,0^069,083,0^069,083,0^069,084,0^069,085,0^069,085,0^068,085,0^068,086,0^068,086,0^067,086,0^067,086,0^066,087,0^066,087,0^066,087,0^065,088,0^064,088,0^064,088,0^063,088,0^063,088,0^063,088,0^062,088,0^062,088,0^062,089,0^061,089,0^061,089,0^061,089,0^061,089,0^061,089,0^061,089,0^061,089,0^061,089,0^061,090,0^061,090,0^062,090,0^062,090,0^062,090,0^062,090,0^062,091,0^062,091,0^062,091,0^063,092,0^063,093,0^063,093,0^063,094,0^063,094,0^064,095,0^064,096,0^064,096,0^064,097,0^065,098,0^065,098,0^065,099,0^065,099,0^065,100,0^066,100,0^066,100,0^066,101,0^066,101,0^066,101,1^078,094,0^078,094,0^078,094,0^078,094,0^078,094,0^078,094,0^078,094,0^078,094,0^078,094,0^078,094,0^078,094,0^078,094,0^078,094,0^078,094,0^078,094,0^078,094,0^078,094,0^078,094,0^078,093,0^078,093,0^078,093,0^078,093,0^078,093,0^078,093,0^077,092,0^077,092,0^077,092,0^077,092,0^077,092,0^076,092,0^076,092,0^076,092,0^076,091,0^076,091,0^075,091,0^075,091,0^075,091,0^074,092,0^074,092,0^074,092,0^073,092,0^073,092,0^073,092,0^073,092,0^073,093,0^073,093,0^072,093,0^072,094,0^072,094,0^072,094,0^071,095,0^071,095,0^071,096,0^071,096,0^071,097,0^072,097,0^072,097,0^072,098,0^072,098,0^072,098,0^073,099,0^073,099,0^073,099,0^074,099,0^074,099,0^074,099,0^074,099,0^075,099,0^075,099,0^075,099,0^075,098,0^075,098,0^076,098,0^076,097,0^076,097,0^076,097,0^077,097,0^077,097,0^077,096,0^077,096,0^077,096,0^077,096,0^077,096,0^077,095,0^077,095,0^077,095,0^077,095,0^077,095,0^077,095,0^077,095,0^077,095,0^077,095,0^077,095,0^077,096,0^077,096,0^077,096,0^077,096,0^077,096,0^077,097,0^077,097,0^077,097,0^077,098,0^077,098,0^077,098,0^077,099,0^077,099,0^077,100,0^077,100,0^077,100,0^078,101,0^078,101,0^078,101,0^078,101,0^078,101,0^079,102,0^079,102,0^079,102,0^079,102,0^080,102,0^080,102,0^080,102,0^080,102,1^091,095,0^091,095,0^091,095,0^091,094,0^091,094,0^091,094,0^091,094,0^091,094,0^091,094,0^091,094,0^090,094,0^090,094,0^090,094,0^090,093,0^090,093,0^090,093,0^090,093,0^090,093,0^090,092,0^089,092,0^089,092,0^089,092,0^089,092,0^089,092,0^088,091,0^088,091,0^088,091,0^087,091,0^087,091,0^087,091,0^087,091,0^086,092,0^086,092,0^086,092,0^085,092,0^085,092,0^084,093,0^084,093,0^084,093,0^083,094,0^083,094,0^083,095,0^083,095,0^082,095,0^082,096,0^082,096,0^082,097,0^082,097,0^082,098,0^082,098,0^082,098,0^083,099,0^083,099,0^083,099,0^084,099,0^084,099,0^084,100,0^084,100,0^085,099,0^085,099,0^085,099,0^086,099,0^086,099,0^086,098,0^087,097,0^087,097,0^087,096,0^087,096,0^088,095,0^088,094,0^088,094,0^089,093,0^089,093,0^089,091,0^089,091,0^090,090,0^090,089,0^090,089,0^090,087,0^090,087,0^091,086,0^091,085,0^091,085,0^091,084,0^091,084,0^092,083,0^092,083,0^092,082,0^092,081,0^092,081,0^092,081,0^092,081,0^092,080,0^092,080,0^092,080,0^092,080,0^092,080,0^092,079,0^092,079,0^092,079,0^092,079,0^092,079,0^092,079,0^092,080,0^092,080,0^092,080,0^092,080,0^092,081,0^092,081,0^092,082,0^092,082,0^091,082,0^091,083,0^091,083,0^091,084,0^090,086,0^090,086,0^090,087,0^090,087,0^089,088,0^089,090,0^089,090,0^089,091,0^089,091,0^088,093,0^088,093,0^088,094,0^088,095,0^088,095,0^088,096,0^088,098,0^088,098,0^087,099,0^087,099,0^087,100,0^088,100,0^088,100,0^088,101,0^088,101,0^088,101,0^088,102,0^088,102,0^088,102,0^088,102,0^088,102,0^089,103,0^089,103,0^089,103,0^089,103,0^089,103,0^089,103,1^102,082,0^102,082,0^102,082,0^102,082,0^102,082,0^102,082,0^102,082,0^102,082,0^102,082,0^102,082,0^102,082,0^102,083,0^102,083,0^102,083,0^101,083,0^101,083,0^101,084,0^101,085,0^101,085,0^101,085,0^101,085,0^101,086,0^100,087,0^100,087,0^100,088,0^099,089,0^099,089,0^099,089,0^099,090,0^098,091,0^098,091,0^098,092,0^097,093,0^097,093,0^096,094,0^096,094,0^096,094,0^095,095,0^095,095,0^095,096,0^094,096,0^094,096,0^094,097,0^094,097,0^093,097,0^093,097,0^093,097,0^093,097,0^093,097,0^093,096,0^093,096,0^093,096,0^093,096,0^094,096,0^094,095,0^094,095,0^094,095,0^095,094,0^095,094,0^095,094,0^095,094,0^096,093,0^097,093,0^097,093,0^097,093,0^098,093,0^098,093,0^098,093,0^098,093,0^099,093,0^099,093,0^099,093,0^100,094,0^100,094,0^100,094,0^100,095,0^100,095,0^100,096,0^100,096,0^100,097,0^100,098,0^100,098,0^100,099,0^100,099,0^100,099,0^100,100,0^100,100,0^100,101,0^100,101,0^100,101,0^100,102,0^100,102,0^100,102,0^100,102,0^100,102,0^099,103,0^099,103,0^099,103,0^099,103,0^099,103,1^103,094,0^103,094,0^103,094,0^104,094,0^104,094,0^104,094,0^104,094,0^104,094,0^104,094,0^104,094,0^104,094,0^104,094,0^104,094,0^104,094,0^104,094,0^104,094,0^104,094,0^104,094,0^104,094,0^104,094,0^104,094,0^104,094,0^104,094,0^105,094,0^105,094,0^105,094,0^106,094,0^106,094,0^107,094,0^107,094,0^107,094,0^108,094,0^108,094,0^109,094,0^110,093,0^110,093,0^110,093,0^110,093,0^111,093,0^111,093,0^111,093,0^111,093,0^111,092,0^111,092,0^110,092,0^110,092,0^110,092,0^110,092,0^109,092,0^108,092,0^108,092,0^108,092,0^107,092,0^107,092,0^106,092,0^106,092,0^105,092,0^105,093,0^105,093,0^104,093,0^104,093,0^104,094,0^104,094,0^104,095,0^104,095,0^104,095,0^105,096,0^105,096,0^106,097,0^107,098,0^107,098,0^108,098,0^108,098,0^110,099,0^111,100,0^111,100,0^113,100,0^115,101,0^115,101,0^115,101,1^

Comment: This question needs more detail.  Can you show an example of 3 byte data and what it would look like in 4 bytes?

Comment: Added 3-byte array data in the question.

Comment: That's too much data.  Just a few samples would have sufficed.  Also, it's still not clear what you want the output to be.